# Swift Tableview Cell button isn't working

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, tableview, cell

I'm having issues getting buttons to work in a tableview cell in Swift. I've looked around at several solutions here and other places around, but nothing has seemed to work. I'm probably missing a simple thing to get it to work properly.

Here's the cell:

```
import UIKit


class AddMealCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var dislikeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var familyMemberLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    
    func configureCell(member: FamilyMembers) {
        dislikeButton.tintColor = UIColor.gray
        likeButton.tintColor = UIColor.green
        self.familyMemberLabel.text = member.name
    }
}
```

And here's the tableview methods from the main VC:

```
extension AddMealViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return familyMembers.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddMealCell", for: indexPath) as? AddMealCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
        
        let member = familyMembers[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(member: member)
        cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeButtonDidTap(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
    
    @objc func likeButtonDidTap(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Like Button Tapped")
    } 
}
```

Everything shows up as it should, but the likeButton isn't selectable (I haven't set up the dislike one yet). I set tableview.delegate and tableview.datasource in viewDidLoad. Not sure what else I'd be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your nib file to say the exact reason! but one of the common issue is because Button appears behind cell.contentView, and contentView grab the touch action sooner than your UIButton. to figure out if this is the reason, set cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = false to see if the reason is this.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem. I ended up just rebuilding/recoding the entire cell and it works now. Not sure what was up with it before.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` in your `cellForRowAt` function.

When this property is `false`, focus events and other events in the event queue will be ignored and you become able to click on your button inside your cell.